# VLC won't play video via HDMI to TV

Tags: laptop, hdmi, vlc, tv

When I connect TV and Laptop via HDMI cable and play a movie with VLC I only get to see the ubuntu desktop, not the VLC output. No video, no audio.
Under Windows it worked like this.
I've googled it, but it seems rather complicated to adjust the settings in Ubuntu.

My laptop is an Asus KJ52, (Nvidia)

Comment: you should make sure your laptop port, HDMI cable and TV are working fine

Comment: When I play movie by HDMI i have to switch on hdmi sound in sound settings myself. You can also try in display settings to check box that all screens displays the same